# Moving data from one Numpy array to another returning incorrect data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using `pandas_market_calendars` to get a market calendar for the NYSE. I set the market calendar to the variable `nyse_calendar` and note that the data type it returns is `<class 'pandas_market_calendars.exchange_calendar_nyse.NYSEExchangeCalendar'>`. This is not helpful since my main data file is stored in a numpy array with data type `<class 'numpy.str_'>`. So I convert the `nyse_calendar` to a numpy array using `.to_numpy()`. When I print the data type of the now it returns `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>`, again not useful as I want to compare my dates and times in my main data file to this calendar.

As such, when I print a **value** from the `trading_days` array, it returns `2011-09-20 13:30:00+00:00`, after converting it to a string.

So, what I am trying to do is loop through `trading_days` (numpy array), and convert the values to string values using a combination of `.split()`. Below is the code to get better context:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas_market_calendars as mkt_cal
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

#set up the NYSE trading calendar
#create new market calendar
nyse_calendar = mkt_cal.get_calendar('NYSE')

#create a dataframe with only trading days - includes early closes
#needs to be from beginning of testing to end of testing data
nyse_schedule = nyse_calendar.schedule(start_date='2011-09-18', end_date='2019-12-05')

#convert dataframe to a numpy array
#reference: trading_days[0,0], trading_days[1,0] etc.
#open date & time in col 0, close date & time in col 1
trading_days = nyse_schedule.to_numpy()

print(trading_days)
>>>[[Timestamp('2011-09-19 13:30:00+0000', tz='UTC')
  Timestamp('2011-09-19 20:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
 [Timestamp('2011-09-20 13:30:00+0000', tz='UTC')
  Timestamp('2011-09-20 20:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
 [Timestamp('2011-09-21 13:30:00+0000', tz='UTC')
  Timestamp('2011-09-21 20:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
 ...
 [Timestamp('2019-12-03 14:30:00+0000', tz='UTC')
  Timestamp('2019-12-03 21:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
 [Timestamp('2019-12-04 14:30:00+0000', tz='UTC')
  Timestamp('2019-12-04 21:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
 [Timestamp('2019-12-05 14:30:00+0000', tz='UTC')
  Timestamp('2019-12-05 21:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')]]

print("trading data type: ",type(trading_days[1,0]))
print("trading data: ", trading_days[1,0])
>>>trading data type:  <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
trading data:  2011-09-20 13:30:00+00:00

#now going to loop through the nyse calendar, convert to string and return in new numpy array
#date, open time, close time
exchng_cal = np.empty((trading_days.shape[0],3),dtype=str)

for i in range(trading_days.shape[0]-1):
    temp_str_open = str(trading_days[i,0])
    print(temp_str_open)
    temp_str_close = str(trading_days[i,1])
    print(temp_str_close)
    #date
    exchng_cal[i,0] = temp_str_open.split()[0]
    print(temp_str_open.split()[0])
    #open time
    exchng_cal[i,1] = temp_str_open.split()[1].split('+')[0]
    print(temp_str_open.split()[1].split('+')[0])
    #close time
    exchng_cal[i,2] = temp_str_close.split()[1].split('+')[0]
    print(temp_str_close.split()[1].split('+')[0])

print(exchng_cal)
>>>2019-12-04 14:30:00+00:00
2019-12-04 21:00:00+00:00
2019-12-04
14:30:00
21:00:00
[['2' '1' '2']
 ['2' '1' '2']
 ['2' '1' '2']
 ...
 ['2' '1' '2']
 ['2' '1' '2']
 ['' '' '']]
```

I have shortened the last print output, but as you can see when I print the individual elements they print with the correct values, but when I print the `exchng_cal` it returns `['2','1','2']`.

Comment: Just a note: with trading_days[1,0], you are printing the first element of the second row.

Comment: Yes @Liuk it's an arbitrary print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In numpy, you have to specify the string length (see `np.chararray`). The default is 1, thus your values get truncated. Because your data structure demands strings of different length, this might be a solution:

```
exchng_cal = np.empty((trading_days.shape[0],3),dtype='object')
```

Comment: Interesting, this works. Thanks for the information on having to specify the string lengths - super helpful.